# Cause CMake to force recompile a file, but only if project is otherwise recompiled?

Tags: cmake

I have generally the same question as in [Can CMake always force the compilation/build of a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203555/can-cmake-always-force-the-compilation-build-of-a-specific-file)

> I have a C++ file using `__DATE__` to display the build date of my app. But if this file is not modified, it will not be rebuilt and the date will not be updated.
>
> Can CMake always rebuild that specific file?

... except I want something slightly different:

In the CMake project I have (for C, transpiles to Makefile which I use), sometimes there are no actual changes to the code when I run `make`, which is detected nicely, in the sense that there is no recompilation (or relinking) of the program.

Obviously, in this case, I do *not* want to update the timestamp, and end up with a new executable, which is otherwise identical to the previous one - apart from the build date.

I have seen in the quoted post, that one simply has to ensure a changed timestamp on the file, to force a recompilation. So, assuming my `__DATE__` usage is in `use_date.c`, what I'd want, is that the timestamp of `use_date.c` is updated (forcing recompilation), only if any other file in the project (say, `main.c`) has been changed, so it forces project recompilation and linking (obviously, this should also work if I just change `use_date.c` manually, and no other file).

So, assuming my project just generates an executable (no libraries):

```
add_executable(my_project use_date.c other_file.c main.c)
```

... is it possible to add a CMake step, that updates the timestamp of `use_date.c` (and thus causes its recompilation), only if otherwise the project is getting recompiled and relinked?

Comment: Not sure if a [`PRE_BUILD` event](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) would be executed, if the target isn't built. Also it's limited to some generators...

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a way: it seems kind of a squeaky solution - hopefully someone more knowledgeable in CMake will post a proper solution eventually. But in the meantime:

I've found that `add_custom_command` with `POST_BUILD` runs the custom command *only* if a new binary (`.elf` for me) is generate, and otherwise does *not* run the custom command.

So, basically, we could have a small bash script in the custom command:

- If this bash script is called, we can assume that POST_BUILD has called it, meaning that a new `.elf` (for whatever other reasons) has been built
- So we can `touch` the `use_date.c`, and while in the `bash` script still, descend into the build directory, and explicitly run `make` again - which should recompile only `use_date.c`, and then link with the rest from the previous build.

This essentially works - except, it causes an infinite loop.

This can get solved with creating a temp file:

- If this bash script is called, we can assume that POST_BUILD has called it, meaning that a new `.elf` (for whatever other reasons) has been built
- check for a temp file:

  - if it does not exist, create it - and then we can `touch` the `use_date.c`, and while in the `bash` script still, descend into the build directory, and explicitly run `make` again - which should ...
  - if it does exist, then we've been called from the second `.elf.` build (for the touched `use_date.c`), so we want to remove the temp file, and just exit - stopping the infinite loop

This seems to work fine:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
                   POST_BUILD
                   DEPENDS ALL
                   #COMMAND bash ARGS -c "touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/use_date.c && cd build && make" ## infinite loop!
                   COMMAND bash ARGS -c "if [ ! -f .refresh ]; then echo '.refresh' | tee .refresh && touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/use_date.c && cd build && make; else rm -v .refresh; fi" # OK!
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   COMMENT "remake with refreshed __DATE__ in use_date.c (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})"
                   VERBATIM
)
```